# User followers count in Deezer through API

Tags: deezer

Is there any way to expose a followers count for a user in Deezer's API?

The current user call exposes a link to the user's profile page which contains a followers count, but there doesn't seem to be any way to return this value through any of the api calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed retrieve the followers of a user by calling the following request : http://api.deezer.com/user/1815162/followers

The result Json will look like this :

{
    "data": [
        /// Here a list of the 25 first users...
    ],
    "total": 42,
    "next": "http://api.deezer.com/user/1815162/followers?index=25"
}

Comment: Thanks Xgouchet! I accidentally overlooked the user methods tab on http://developers.deezer.com/api/user